# getting unique strings and ordering them alphabetically and getting frequency of words

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String array containing Strings (words with no punctuation marks, all lower case).
What I need to do is to get all those strings, and store them alphabetically with the highest frequency first. E.g the output should be something like this:
it - 2
of - 2
the - 2
times -2
was - 2
best - 1
worst - 1

The amount of string in my array is over 200 strings.
I have stored my strings in the array called IndividualWords, like this:

```
    String[] IndividualWords = stringfrominterface.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");;
        ArrayList <String> uniquestrings = new ArrayList<>();


for(int i =0; i < IndividualWords.length ; i++){
            if(!uniquestrings.contains(IndividualWords[i])){
                uniquestrings.add(IndividualWords[i]);
            }
        }
```

The thing is that I dont know how to do that. I know how to get the unique words but cant really find a way or think of a way to get the frequencies of words and to output them alphabeically...

Comment: May I ask, is this homework?

Comment: Show your code (what you tried), and explain why it "didn't end too well". Then we can help you understand why it didn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried sorting them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
private static class WordComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    Map<String, Integer> map;

    public WordComparator(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return -1 * Integer.compare(map.get(o1), map.get(o2));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] IndividualWords = new String[] { "test", "test", "ok", "ok1", "ok1", "ok1", "ok1" };
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : IndividualWords) {
        Integer occurence = wordMap.get(word);
        wordMap.put(word, occurence == null ? 1 : occurence+1);
    }
    System.out.println("BEFORE: " +wordMap);
    TreeMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new WordComparator(wordMap));
    sortedMap.putAll(wordMap);
    System.out.println("AFTER: " +sortedMap);

}
```

That was fun ;)